JasperReports Server has cut community support, alternative open source suggestions as java reporter tool?
Can I still access older versions of JasperReports Server community edition?

We are no longer  hosting downloads of JasperReports Server community
edition.  Jaspersoft Documentation


Jaspersoft has cut jasperreport server community support and is not allowing downloads. What alternative can be suggested instead?

In the FAQ, there is a link to the latest community edition:

The latest version is available for download here.

(archive.org version of the page.)
Registration (with validation of the account) is required to download the the software. There is a relevant discussion of the availability of the latest community edition here.
Note that there seems a lot of data collected:

Jaspersoft Studio collects usage statistics on how the user interacts with the application. The data collection process involves:

End User Data:
Installation UUID:  Each Jaspersoft Studio installation is identified by a unique ID.
User Email: After providing the Community account credentials, the user email is associated with the installation UUID.

Logs Data:
Information on actions taken during the usage of the software including  IP address, OS version, Java version, events such as
creation of a new report, export format, language used for report
expressions.




Thank you for your quick response, when we look at the downloads section in the Community version, there is no JasperReport Server option. JasperSoft Community

You could try ART (A Reporting Tool) - https://sourceforge.net/projects/art/
